# Rails 3 widget helper partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, partials

I ran into a big problem in moving my application to Rails 3. I have a view helper which i call 'WidgetHelper'. It helps to render some partials automatically when i refer to it. For example

```
<%= widget('loginbox', :global => true) %>
```

But it not works correctly. It renders HTML code as I want, but escapes the return value, what is not expected. How can I tell to render (or to something) to *not* escape the return value for me?

Here is my code:

```
  def widget(widget, options={})
    begin
      unless options[:fullpath]
        render :partial => widget_path(widget, options[:global])
      else
        render "widgets/#{widget}"
      end
    rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
      "<!-- widget: #{widget.inspect}, #{options.inspect} -->"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def widget(widget, options={})
  begin
    unless options[:fullpath]
      raw render(:partial => widget_path(widget, options[:global]))
    else
      raw render("widgets/#{widget}"))
    end
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
    raw "<!-- widget: #{widget.inspect}, #{options.inspect} -->"
  end
end
```

The `raw` method of Rails 3 does the reverse of `h` method in Rails 2. Escaping a string was done with the `h` method on Rails 2. On Rails 3, strings output from a view are escaped by default, and the escaping can be disabled by the `raw` method.

Comment: Thank you, it works well. I add score for you and for @Jamie Wong too, because i used both solution in my app.

Comment: This seems kind of backwards in my mind - when would you ever want widget without raw? Specifying you want the raw should be part of the definition in my mind, not the invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 changed the way that content filtering works - it by default assumes you want everything filtered.

You can correct this using `html_safe`:

`"<!-- widget: #{widget.inspect}, #{options.inspect} -->".html_safe`

See: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3